# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[MKAnnotation]' and 'MKAnnotation'

Tags: swift, tvos, mkannotationview

I'm working on a tvOS app, where I want to be able to swipe between annotations.  I store my annotations in a Dictionary, and store the Dictionary in an Array for future use.  I am simply plotting three annotations for Canada, USA, and Mexico.  I want to be able to swipe on the remote between these annotations.  When an annotation is clicked, it will take you to information about that country.

```
let countriesArray = ["Canada", "Mexico", "United States of America"]  
var annotationArray = [MKPointAnnotation]()  
var locationDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()  
var locationArray = [AnyObject]()
```

Once the three countries are plotted, my array looks like the following:

```
locationArray [{  
    annotation = "<MKPointAnnotation: 0x7fc021b01f70>";  
    country = Canada;  
    latitude = "71.47385399229037";  
    longitude = "-96.81064609999999";  
}, {  
    annotation = "<MKPointAnnotation: 0x7fc0219dcf90>";  
    country = "United States of America";  
    latitude = "37.99472997055178";  
    longitude = "-95.85629150000001";  
}, {  
    annotation = "<MKPointAnnotation: 0x7fc02260ff70>";  
    country = Mexico;  
    latitude = "23.94480686844645";  
    longitude = "-102.55803745";  
}]
```

When the Apple remote is swipped, down, for example, I'm getting the following error on the if condition below.

Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[MKAnnotation]' and 'MKAnnotation'

How can I compare the annotation in the arrary to the one selected?

```
func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {  
    print("Down")  

    let selectedAnnotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations  

    for x in 0 ... locationArray.count - 1 {  

        let value = locationArray[x].valueForKey("annotation") as! MKAnnotation  

        if  selectedAnnotation == value {   //error

            let currentLocation = locationArray[x].valueForKey("country")  

            print("Your on \(currentLocation)")  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mapView.selectedAnnotations` returns an array of `MKAnnotation`s, i.e. an `[MKAnnotation]`, comparing it to a single `MKAnnotation` value with `operator ==` does not work. You need to decide what to do with multiple values from the array - specifically, whether the comparison should be true when any of the annotations in the array matches `value`, or when the first one matches `value`, or all of them match `value`.

If you need to check that one array element matches the value, you can use `contains`, like this:

```
if  (selectedAnnotation.contains { $0.title == value.title && $0.subtitle == value.subtitle }) {
    let currentLocation = locationArray[x].valueForKey("country")  
    print("Your on \(currentLocation)")  
}
```

**Edit:** The initial attempt at using non-closure `contains` has failed, because `MKAnnotation` does not conform to `Equatable` protocol. Thanks, [dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395203/dan), for catching this!

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Your suggestions throws the following: `Cannot convert value of type 'MKAnnotation' to expected argument type '@noescape (MKAnnotation) throws -> Bool'`

Comment: @PaulS. This is very odd. What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: It's because the non-closure version of contains requires the elements to be `Equatable` which `MKAnnotation` is not.

Comment: @dan Good catch, thank you very much! I edited to fix the problem.

Comment: Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014).  When I make the edit, I get the following `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String??' and 'String?'`

Comment: Changing to `(selectedAnnotation.contains { $0.title!! == value.title})` resolve the issue.  Also, I don't need the subtitle, so I omitted it.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @PaulS. I don't like optionals. Why can't Swift figure them out for me auto-magically? Anyway, I'm glad that this has worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

1- `[MKAnnotation]` is an array of `MKAnnotation` , can you notice the difference?

2- `let selectedAnnotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations` here, you are storing all the annotations not the current one, can you notice the s in this statement `mapView.selectedAnnotations` ?

Comment: Adding .first to `let selectedAnnotation = mapView.selectedAnnotations.first` selects the first annotation.  changing my comparison to `let value = locationArray[x].valueForKey("annotation") as! MKPointAnnotation
            
            if  selectedAnnotation as! MKPointAnnotation == value  {
` seems to work.