# Error Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'MKAnnotation' operands

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I understand that there were many given question related with my problem, but me nothing have helped. How can I fix this error?

My code:

```
var indexValue = 0
    for annotationInMap in mapView.annotations {

        if annotation == annotationInMap {
            let centerInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))

            centerInfo.text = allStudios[indexValue].studioAddress
            centerInfo.numberOfLines = 0
            centerInfo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

            annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = centerInfo
        }

        indexValue = indexValue + 1
    }
```

In this line: `if annotation == annotationInMap` i got an error `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'MKAnnotation' operands`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Binary operator == cannot be applied to two MKAnnotation operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376706/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-mkannotation-and?rq=1)

Comment: Did you create a custom `MKAnnotation` class and added it to `mapView`?

Comment: @AhmadF It's annotationView

Comment: @ImadAli I don't think it is a duplicate of that question. In the linked question, there was an attempt to compare an annotation to an array of annotations.

Comment: @JeremyP I think so too

Answer (score 4):

Only types that conform to the `Equatable` protocol can be compared with the `==` operator. `MKAnnotation` does not conform to the protocol, that is why you get the error.

You can use the `===` identity operator which checks if the two objects have the same reference.

Comment: Got `Index out of range`, but `indexValue = (Int) 7` i got in debug area

Comment: That's a different error now. You should make sure that your array actually has an object at the specified index.

Comment: I understand what me need should make sure that my array actually has an object, but i don't understand how to do it :(

Comment: @onpro `allStudios.count` will tell you if there is anything in the array

Comment: @JeremyP Yes, have 6 indexes. If i use code like this `for index in 0..<allAddress.count {
        print("index \(index)");
        centerInfo.text = allAddress[index].address;
        print("address - \(allAddress[index].address)");
    }`

i get 6 index and 6 addresses, but on each annotationView i see the same text

Comment: @onpro You clearly have more annotations than there are entries in that array. I agree with Yannick that it is a different question and probably can't be diagnosed in the comments here.

Comment: @JeremyP you think that i should create another question with this problem?

Comment: @onpro there are plenty of questions regarding this issue here on SO.

Comment: @onpro well not straight away. You should try debugging your code yourself first and also see if anybody else has already come across the issue (unlikely if it is an issue with your programming logic).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376877/8294374

check here the answer. or you can cast

```
(annotation as AnyObject).isEqual(annotationInMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Instead of using the binary operator you should use method "isEqual"

```
   for annotationInMap in mapView.annotations {

       if annotation.isEqual(annotationInMap) {
          // handled this annotation
          // ...
       }            
    }
```